# How do I dynamically update total price with jquery?

Tags: jquery, function, var

I have this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liamtarpey/qMZCq/) which is working quite nicely, I'm trying to calculate total price of a product using jQuery and select boxes.

I have one issue however, when the second select option of 'black widow' is selected, the data-value is updated depending on what is selected in the first select box.

data-value is 100 (when 1x12 cabinet is selected)
data-value is 200 (when 2x12 cabinet is selected)
data-value is 400 (when 4x12 cabinet is selected)

This is all updating correctly (I have checked in Chrome Inspect and the data-value is updating), however, once the black widow option has been selected once, the total price refuses to dynamically update.

Can anyone please clarify why this is? Is there a way to re-load the updateTotal variable everytime a option is changed? I assumed this is what it was doing but clearly not.

Here is my js:

```
//Calculate Total Price
    $("select[name='options']").change(function() { 
        updateTotal(); 
    });

//Function for price calculator
function updateTotal() {
    var newTotal = 0;
    $("select[name='options'] option:selected").each(function() {
        newTotal += parseFloat($(this).data('value'));
    });
    $(".total").text(newTotal);
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Its working fine for me. I can select black widow then change the cabinet type and it updates...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain clearly, it's actually updating based on the data-value of the #cab select rather than #cab and #speaker. 

For example is 4x12 Cabinet and Black widow are selected, it should output a value of 404.

Comment: It does exactly that for me. Have you tried using onDomready instead of onLoad?

Comment: I have set the data-values in the first #cab select to '0' to make this a little clearer.

Comment: Again, I don't see any problems with your jsFiddle. I can select 4x12 and Black Widow and the output is 404. I am using Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, @gwin003, could you possibly try it now? I've set the other data-values to 0 to make this clearer, please set it to Black Widow and then try selecting through the first box, nothing changes

Comment: Why would it change? If your data-values for the first drop down are 0, your total will never change. Your total will basically just be the value from the second dropdown, which is 100 when I pick black widow. I apologize if I am not understanding you correctly, but I dont see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @gwin003, it's the data-values of the 'black widow' option that change, depending on what is selected in the first select box. For example if 4x12 + black widow is selected it should output 400; if 2x12 + black widow is selected it should output 200 etc... Sorry if I explained this badly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
$(".widow").attr('data-value', price[$(this).val()]);
```

To this :

```
$(".widow").data('value', price[$(this).val()]);
```

See the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMZCq/16/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorted my issue out completely! :)